# Установка vue и axios в laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

У меня сайт на laravel. Помогите разобраться с установкой этих пакетов. В документации к laravel указано как устанавливать vue через npm. Но я не понимаю куда и где это устанавливается и подключается. При вводе этой команды у меня во всех шаблонах блейд автоматически подключится vue? Я, конечно же, понимаю, что такого быть не может, потому что названия этих шаблонов придуманы мной и в настройках фреймворка для установки vue вряд ли фигурируют. Я не использую app.js, так как у меня подключены свои файлы.

Еще вопрос: как подключить axios?

Comment: Ну в вашем случае, возможно, и Vue будет удобнее через CDN подключить. А если хотите именно как npm пакеты, то тут уже систему сборки настраивать придется

Comment: А как подключить axios?

Comment: Да все так же, скорее всего. `unpkg.com/vue` - для Vue, `unpkg.com/axios` - для axios. UPD: с axios такое решение "в лоб" не прокатит, так что смотрите ссылку под ответом AK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно понять, что вопрос "где это настраивается" делится на две большие части: на разработку на локальной машине и на продакшн сервер.

Когда вы читаете в интернете советы по установке где фигурируют команды типа `npm install vue axios` - это речь идёт в типичном случае про локальный ваш компьютер.

Подразумевается, что у вас либо установлен node.js с официального сайта (включает в себя набор npm), либо есть какой-то типовой веб-сервер (например, openserver) в котором много различных утилит для удобства разработки.

Типично для этого режима запускать скрипты в режиме dev для удобства отладки.

Когда речь идёт о продакшн сервере - то как правило никто эти команды уже не даёт и подключается уже production версия скриптов (минифицированная, собранная в бандлы). И доставка этих бандлов идёт при помощи какой-либо системы сборки.

В довольно простом сценарии если у вас исходники сайта лежат в git можено сделать так. При локальной разработке подключают пакеты (`npm i`), пишут и проверяют работу скриптов, а потом коммитят собранные скрипты в гит. Когда на сайте происходит обновление исходников - подкачивается актуальная версия скриптов.

В принципе, установка vue через npm может вами и не применяться на начальных этапах изучения работы - если вы вручную подключаете скрипты, просто npm даёт удобство при обновлении версий пакетов, так как автоматически отслеживает десятки и сотни зависимостей между пакетами.

Comment: А как же подключить axios?

Comment: @ArturHan Прямо говоря, я всегда axios подключал только через npm, так что даже не представляю, как его подключить напрямую. Пришлось гуглить, вот смотрите в офрепозитории способ подключения через cdn: https://github.com/axios/axios